# Android build is rejected in play store due to READ_SMS permission + React Native

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, react-native-permissions

Our app is rejected in play store as we are using the below permission.

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>`

Our requirement is to send a message to customer care support from user app in a standard format, and we will write the SMS in standard format, when user press on Submit button it will open messages app with default message written in it, all user has to do is just press send. As we cannot remove this SMS functionality, so we cannot remove the above permission.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need SEND_SMS permission. From your explanation there is no reason to ask for READ_SMS and this is probably the reason they are rejecting your app. So request SEND_SMS instead.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: I am using 'react-native-sms' library, when I change permission from READ_SMS to SEND_SMS, it is not working. Any other library or proper reference where I can refer, please assist.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the default SMS Handler. so check this guideline.

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers?hl=en
2. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?hl=en&visit_id=637480440675554570-517489570&rd=1#intended